# Converting Decimal Number to Binary

Tags: javascript

I found this code on W3schools for converting decimal into binary.

```
function dec2bin(dec){
return (dec >>> 0).toString(2);
}
```

I don't understand what is the purpose for making zero fill right shift in this case? What is the use of setting the shift to 0 (i.e. dec >>> 0) since as I know it doesn't push any binary digit to the right at all?

I am a JS beginner. Thanks!

Comment: It converts a number to an integer. It’s the same as `dec | 0` or `~~dec`.

Comment: @Xufox, not only, it makes a 32 bit number.

Comment: you can manually check difference between >> and >>> and compare results

Comment: @Banzay This question isn’t about the difference between `>>` and `>>>`.